# Are the cuspidal and Eisenstein parts of an integral modular form also integral?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-forms

From the general theory of modular forms, we have the orthogonal decomposition:
$$M_2(\Gamma_1(N))=S_2(\Gamma_1(N))\oplus\mathrm{Eis}_2(\Gamma_1(N)).$$

So for $f\in M_2(\Gamma_1(N))$, we write $f=f_\mathrm{cus}+f_\mathrm{eis}$ accordingly.

$\textbf{My question is:}$ If $f$ has integer coefficients, then is it true that $f_\mathrm{cus}$ and $f_\mathrm{eis}$ also have integer coefficients?

For a generic vector space with a decomposition and a fixed choice of integral submodule, this kind of question is false. But, in this specific case it seems to be true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's false; and it is false in a way that is interesting enough that people have written hundreds of papers studying exactly how and why it fails. :-)

The fact that the "cuspidal + Eisenstein" decomposition doesn't work integrally is closely related to the fact that there exist nontrivial *congruences* between cusp forms and Eisenstein series. These Eisenstein congruences are crucial in all sorts of deep research, e.g. the line of work that started with Ribet's converse to Herbrand's theorem and continued via Mazur and Wiles' proof of the Iwasawa main conjecture.

Comment: Exactly, it is false in a highly non-trivial, interesting way. :)

Comment: I am happy to know that it was not a trivial question. Thank you so much for this answer; it was very enlightening! On a tangential question: Do you know if this phenomenon is somehow related to the "congruence number" as studied by Ribet and others? In some sense, the congruence number of a modular form $f$ measures the failure of the integral decomposition between the span of $f$ and its orthogonal complement. However, it is usually defined taking into account only the cuspidal part of the space. So, I thought (naively) that the integral decomposition with the Eisenstein part should hold.

Comment: Related but distinct. Whenever you have a decomposition of your space as a direct sum of two subspaces, you can define a congruence ideal measuring the extent to which the decomposition fails to be integral. For the decomposition "f-eigenspace" + "everything else" you get Ribet's congruence ideal. For the decomposition "Eis series" + "cusp forms" you get some other ideal (related to Bernoulli numbers + thus to class groups of cyclotomic fields).

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed a very interesting subject! So, if I understand correctly, in the work of Ribet, Hida, Stein and others (concerning these numbers), they usually study a congruence number that measures the failure of the integral decomposition (A): "$f$-eigenspace" + "everything else in $S_2(N)$". However, for a project, I had to work with (B): "$f$-eigenspace" + "everything else in $M_2(N)$".

Comment: I was expecting the integrality of the decomposition "cusp forms"+"Eis series" to hold, so that the failure of (B) could also be measured by the congruence number from (A). But, I was mistaken. I am very grateful for your answer and further clarification!